# Sort table by background-color of last cell in row

Tags: jquery, sorting, html-table

Is it possible to sort a table on page load by a css attribute of the last cell in a row? I want the table rows sorted by the bg-color of it's last cell.

Table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td style="font-weight:bold; background-color:#dee">Foo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td style="background-color:#ffa">Foo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>put me on top</td>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td style="background-color:#eee">Foo</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have no idea where to start but I can alert the colors as RGB at least:

```
$("table tr").find("td:last").each(function(index) {
    alert($(this).css("background-color"));
});
```

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/AqTTJ/6/

Comment: what do you mean 'sort'? you need to be more specific. do you want to just check if an element has, lets say, `#eee`, and if so, put it at the top?

Comment: You want to sort by hexadeximal? Or by `rgb()` components? Or alphabetically by colour?

Comment: Sorry if this was not clear. I want the table rows sorted by the bg-color of it's last cell. See http://jsfiddle.net/AqTTJ/2/ - Defining a sort list by the hex code would be top notch but google says this is complicated.

Comment: I could also add some css class tho.

Comment: If you add classes then you should be able to use getClass and do the sorting from there.

Comment: color sort is not in alphabetic order in demo `Desired Result` table... really not clear what sort order needs to be. This demo sorts RGB  but result is not same as yours http://jsfiddle.net/AqTTJ/5/

Comment: I want to define a list. e.g. sort by "#eee, #dee, #ffa"

Comment: Your result table is in following order `#eee , #dee, #ffa`  clearly not in any sortable order

Comment: UNless you are going to always have specific colors and want to set the specific color at top... not clear in explanation.

Comment: So sorry, I wasn't aware that this is so unclear :/ I simply want to sort the rows by a manually defined list of background colors, e.g. `#eee, #dee, #ffa` or `#dee, #ffa, #eee`, whatever

Comment: in that case you need to define the specific colors so they can be put into an array to compare to or use colors that sort alphabetically producing order you want. Can see what happens in alphabetic sort in demo I did

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code sorts rows by a manual key or by background-color integer values. You can try it out here on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SeJWD/).

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Variable declarations:
  var tableId = '#table';
  var autoSort = true;
  var rowArr = getRows(tableId);
  var keySort = [];

  // Add a click handler to the sort button
  // that will call autoSortKeys() and pass
  // in either a manual key array or an
  // auto-sorted array.
  $('#sort').click(function() {
    autoSort = $('#autoSort').is(':checked');
    keySort = autoSort
        ? autoSortKeys(rowArr)
        : [0xffee77, 0xaaffaa, 0xff6666];
    sortTable(tableId, rowArr, keySort);
  });
});

// Sorts a table based on the array of
// keys that are passed into the function.
function sortTable(tableId, rows, keys) {
  $(tableId).empty();
  $.each(keys, function(indexK, valueK) {
    $.each(rows, function(indexR, valueR) {
      if (valueR[0] === valueK) {
        $(tableId).append(valueR[1]);
      }
    });
  });
}

// Converts an rgb() value returned from Jquery
// into an integer value for comparison.
function rgbToInt(color) {
  var digits = /(.*?)rgb\((\d+), (\d+), (\d+)\)/.exec(color);
  var red = parseInt(digits[2]);
  var green = parseInt(digits[3]);
  var blue = parseInt(digits[4]);
  return parseInt((blue | (green << 8) | (red << 16)), 10);
};

// Stores every row in a table designated table
// as a sub-array comprised of the background color
// integer value and the row DOM element.
function getRows(tableId) {
  var arr = new Array();
  $(tableId+' tr').each(function() {
    var bg = $(this).find('td:last-child').css('backgroundColor');
    var key = rgbToInt(bg);
    arr.push([key, $(this)]); // [bg-color, <tr />]
  });
  return arr;
}

// Automatically sorts rows based on their background
// color integer value from highest to lowest.
function autoSortKeys(arr) {
  var keys = new Array();
  $.each(arr, function(index, value) {
    keys.push(value[0]);
  });
  var uniqueKeys = new Array();
  $.each(keys, function(index, value){
    if($.inArray(value, uniqueKeys ) === -1)
      uniqueKeys.push(value);
  });
  delete keys; // garbage collect
  return uniqueKeys .sort().reverse();
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>Foo</td>
    <td>Foo</td>
    <td style="font-weight:bold; background-color:#fe7">One</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Foo</td>
    <td>Foo</td>
    <td style="font-weight:bold; background-color:#fe7">One</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Foo</td>
    <td>Foo</td>
    <td style="background-color:#f66">Three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Foo</td>
    <td>Foo</td>
    <td style="font-weight:bold; background-color:#fe7">One</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Foo</td>
    <td>Foo</td>
    <td style="background-color:#afa">Two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Foo</td>
    <td>Foo</td>
    <td style="background-color:#f66">Three</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />
<label for="autoSort"> Auto Sort </label>
<input type="checkbox" id="autoSort" checked="CHECKED" />
<input type="button" id="sort" value="Sort" />
```

Comment: this is nice but I don't understand how I can define a custom order?

Comment: You can't unless you explicitly say what order you want the rows to be in. Your post said you wanted to order by background color.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eWq5X/3/ - #f66 rows on top, #fe7 rows in teh middle, #afa rows at the bottom

Comment: [Here is a hacky way](http://jsfiddle.net/WBBAd/). All I did was move the last row before the first one... Sorted?

Comment: SEE NEW ANSWER - I changed the row Map to a 2D Array, because the map keys were being overwritten due to the colors not being unique.

Comment: wow! works like a charm! Your effort is highly appreciated :)